# How to close command line window after closing script running on web browser?

Tags: python, browser, command-line-interface, plotly-dash

I am running a dash application through cmd and after closing the web browser (https//127.0.0.1/8050)  on which the dash application is running, I want to close the command line window from where the program was initially run. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Could you clarify the problem? Usually command line windows have little "X" in the right upper corner. Why you could not close your command line window?

Comment: @np8 I can manually close the cmd line window by pressing the "X" button but i want to know if its possible to write some code that will automatically close the cmd window when i close my dash application ie web browser

Comment: Making such functionality will be very tricky since the web browser does not send anything to the web pages when the browser / tab is closed. However, I guess it still might be possible somehow, since probably big companies like facebook somehow record the screentime of the users and know when user "is active". So, the first step is to create some logic to your webapp that checks if there is a user connected to your page. Maybe that would be another SO question, that could also be of interest to others?

Comment: I asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62854394/how-to-check-number-of-active-users-in-dash-app). You could close your webapp when the count of users goes to zero.

Comment: @np8 fair enough. If not this, then do you have any idea how I can close the development server (Flask server which on which my dash app is running) when I close the web browser? Usually I close the browser and then press 'Ctrl+C' in CLI to exit the Flask server but is there any code that can automate this step ?

Comment: I think the solution would be roughly the same for closing a dash app and closing a Flask server automatically when there are no users, since dash runs on a Flask server. Is there a reason the cmd window should be closed and the server killed when user closes the browser? How about just running the server without a command line window and letting it be there in the background always?

Comment: Yes actually this is a requirement for a project I am doing. The code has to be run in the command line and the server has to close upon closing the browser

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a small javascript function for this. So first when the application is started from your command line, get `process id` of the process that gets started, and pass this to a variable in dash. There are many ways of retrieving this process id.

Then an event listerner in javascript like so:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = '';
});
```

Finally in add a kill event using the process id you have collected at the start

```
GetObject("winmgmts:").Get("Win32_Process.Handle='" + pid + "'").Terminate();
```

Here is the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources) for adding extra js to the dash application.

Comment: thanks for your help but the solution did not work. I created a .js file in the /assets directory and wrote the code you have given in that file after storing processid in variable 'pid'

Comment: what is the error you get? If you add code snippets to your question to show what you have tried, it would be easier to help.